# couchbase cluster and nodejs distributed architecture

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I am working on a nodejs framework which is distributed (multi-process) architecture. It can integrate several physics servers with nodejs apps together. Just wonder if I can deploy a nodejs app on a physical server, at same time I can install a couchbase on the same physics server.

thus node app on multi physical servers compose distributed system, and installed couchbases on multi physical servers to compose the cluster.

Or I have to install the couchbase to the separate physical servers(not on the same server where node app is) to construct cluster?

your comment welcome

**Updated question**

Comment: I assume you mean physical servers, but I don't understand what your programming question is? If you install a cluster on one server, you risk having a single point of failure.

Comment: I mean couchbase are deployed to the same physics server with web apps, web apps on different physics server compose distributed architecture, couchbase on different physics server compose cluster

Comment: You can install them wherever you'd like. You may find it won't perform as well depending on the memory requirements of you application and database sever. You've said "physics" many times, but I think you mean **physical**. Again, what's your programming question?

Comment: Like @WiredPrairie has said yes it would be possible to host couchbase on the same physical server as your nodejs processes BUT they are both going to be competing for CPU,RAM,I/O,Network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For production systems, it's generally best practice to isolate concerns. Your application servers should be "stateless" in the sense that you can add more or remove them without an implications except scaling for user connections. The database is stateful so you typically separate them into their own cluster to handle the data servicing load and you don't add/remove servers as often.

If you combine the two into nodejs-couchbase servers, you will need to add couchbase nodes as well as app server (nodejs) nodes as your user traffic increases, however this is not proportional to the user traffic. Each Couchbase node will likely service multiple app servers easily so your proportions/ratios will be wrong for the user traffic in terms of users:app servers:Couchbase servers.